# Stackoverflow exception (0xc00000fd) on Windows Server 2016

Tags: c#, winforms, clr, windows-server-2016

I made winforms app which running fine on my win8, but on windows server 2016 it crashes before window appears. I found this in Event Viewer:

> Faulting application name: MyApp.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp:
>   0x597b5764 Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.6.1648.0, time
>   stamp: 0x58e3fbcf Exception code: 0xc00000fd  Fault offset: 0x0045068d
>   Faulting process id: 0x9078 ...

Maybe this will be helpfull: 32bits application using external dlls dynamicaly, but it crashes before using assembly.

Is anyone had similiar issue and solve this?

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was LineShape object on Form, when I delete it everything is OK.